# Accessing nest elements by their keys with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have the following nest:

```
var myNest = [
  {"key":"1","values":[...]},
  {"key":"2","values":[...]},
  {"key":"3","values":[...]},
]
```

How can I access these elements using their keys?

I know I can access them by their index

```
myNext[0] //return elements with key=="1"
myNest[1] //return elements with key=="2"
```

But what I would like to do is:

```
myNest["1"] //return elements with key=="1"
myNest["2"] //return elements with key=="2"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map()` instead of `entries()` when building your nest. You probably did something similar to this:

```js
var products = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cat Hat",
  "price": 49
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Unicorn Boots",
  "price": 139
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Pink Woolly Jumper",
  "price": 34
}];


var productsById = d3.nest()
  .key(function(p) {
    return p.id;
  })
  .entries(products);

console.log(productsById)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If instead you use `map()`:

```js
var products = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cat Hat",
  "price": 49
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Unicorn Boots",
  "price": 139
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Pink Woolly Jumper",
  "price": 34
}];


var productsById = d3.nest()
  .key(function(p) {
    return p.id;
  })
  .map(products);

console.log(productsById)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You get a map where you can access objects by their key directly, e.g. with `productsById["2"]` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You could us a hash table, where the key of your object is the key for the object itselft.

For ES6 I suggest to use a Map:

```js
var myNest = [{ key: "1", values: [1, 4] }, { key: "2", values: [2, 5] }, { key: "3", values: [3, 6] }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

myNest.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.key] = a;
});

console.log(hash['2']);
```